# Branch Protection Rule on GitHub

Tags: github, branch, branching-and-merging

Is it possible to enable branch protection rules at the organisation level in GitHub so that all repositories that are part of that organisation inherit these rules for the applied branches. Right now it's really a hassle to enable those same set of rules on a per repo basis for same set of branches.  How can we achieve this?

Right now it's really a hassle to enable those same set of rules on a per repo basis for same set of branches.

Answer (score 3):

> Right now, it's really a hassle to enable those same set of rules on a per repo basis for same set of branches. How can we achieve this?

This should change starting Apr. 2023:

> ### [Introducing Repository Rules Public Beta](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-04-17-introducing-repository-rules-public-beta) (Apr. 2023)
>
> Today we are announcing the public beta of repository rules!
>
> Repository rules are GitHub's next evolution of branch protections to help make your repositories more secure and compliant at scale.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7575792/229238416-32e3a767-2d4a-404a-a28a-5a778c3371db.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of ruleset overview]
>
> Rules allow you to easily define protections for branches and tags in your repositories and, if you are a GitHub Enterprise Cloud customer, to enforce them across your organization.
> It is also easier for everyone collaborating on your repositories to know what rules are in place.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7575792/229236946-f91a103c-112f-4f84-b3e0-e8393703e4b8.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of creating a ruleset]
>
> At the core of rules is the ability to define rulesets.
> A ruleset is a collection of rules that are enforced together.
> For example, you could require that all commits to a branch are signed and that those commits have two reviewers.
> Rulesets can also be applied to tags, allowing you to enforce rules on releases.
>
> The ruleset page is the central place to view and manage all the rules for a repository.
> It shows the rules that are currently in place and allows you to add new rulesets or edit existing ones.
>
> When creating a ruleset, you define its enforcement status as `active` or `disabled`.
> Active rulesets must pass for a commit to be merged, while `disabled` rulesets are not enforced; they will not prevent merges but allow admins to craft rules before enforcing them.Enterprise Cloud customers can also `evaluate` rulesets: a "dry run" mode for understanding the impact of new rules before they are `active` and enforced.
>
> It's also easier to target branches and tags in rulesets, with options to select the default branch, all branches, and branches or tags that match an `fnmatch` pattern.
> You can add multiple patterns to a ruleset to apply it to different branch and tag naming styles.
>
> You can always know what rules are in place for a repository.
>
> Anyone with read access to a repository can view its rules and what they mean.
> The rulesets overview is linked from the branches page by clicking the shield icon, and from a pull request, and from the output of the Git CLI when rules block a push.
>
> From here, you can filter rules by branches or tags to understand how a rule might be enforced on your next push.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7575792/229240158-4a0f407f-3211-4a78-95f8-d5bfa56c77f4.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of read only view of rules]
>
> Repository rules are now available to all GitHub cloud customers.
> To get started, visit the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets) to learn how to enable and use rules.
>
> For Enterprise Cloud customers, visit the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets) to learn about organization rulesets and more.
>
> We want to hear from you on how we can improve repository rules! Join the conversation in the repository rules [public beta discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52652).

See more about "**[Available rules for rulesets](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets)**".

As the "[Managing rulesets for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/managing-rulesets-for-a-repository)" mentions:

> If you're the owner of an organization, you can create rulesets at the organization level.
>
> You can apply these rulesets to specific repositories in your organization, and to specific branches in those repositories. For more information, see "[Managing rulesets for repositories in your organization.](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-rulesets-for-repositories-in-your-organization)"

Answer (score 0):

There is no organization level default option to set a branch protection for all repositories in an org.

If this is something you don't want to repetitively do by hand, you can take a look at [the GitHub API for Branch Protection](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branch-protection#update-branch-protection). That way you can run a short script whenever you setup a new repo or have a job run periodically that sets and confirms the branch protection for all repos in the org at once.